# How to create bootstrap's popovers dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to create a function that's include a popover that will be fired by three elements, only the placement and content will be changed.
The code below works only for the first parameter, what am I doing wrong?

```
function popTeste(arguments) {
    var args = Array.from(arguments);
    args.forEach(function (e, i) {
        console.log(e);
        $('body').popover({
            selector: e.selector
            , trigger: e.trigger || 'hover'
            , placement: e.placement || 'top'
            , html: true
            , container: 'body'
            , title: e.title || 'Info - ' + (i + 1) + '</i>'
            , template: '<div class="popover popInfoFunc' + i + '" role="tooltip" style="height: 161px"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title" style="height: auto; padding: 5px;"><i></i></h3><div class="popover-content" style="width: 400px; padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;"></div></div>'
            , content: '<div id="' + i + '"><i id="spinnerPopover" style="margin: 40px 0px 0px 186px" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></i></div>' //dynamic content loaded by AJAX

        });
    });
}
```

The function call:

```
popTeste(
    {
        trigger: 'hover'
        , selector: '#btnInfoFuncionario'
        , login: "$(this).closest('tr').data('id')"
    },
    {
        trigger: 'hover'
        , placement: 'left'
        , selector: '#btnInfoFuncionarioModal'
        , login: "$(this).closest('.input-group').find('#ttb').data('id')"
    }

);
```

Comment: Maybe is bs youre not using "pOptions"?

Comment: pOptions is just the name of parameter, arguments are all data send as parameter